# setAttributes conditional Formatting

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a search script that I am using to search a spreadsheet. One of the returned values is a date. On the spreadsheet it looks like `mm/dd/yyyy` but in the text box it shows a full date like `Fri May 10 2013 03:00:00 GMT` The code line looks like:

`txt1.setText(data[nn][14]);`

How do I make it look like mm/dd/yyyy 01/26/2013?
 I tried

`var date = (Date(data[nn][14]), "EST", "MM/dd/yyyy")` but it literally shows MM/dd/yyyy

Also I have `txt1.setText(data[nn][0]).setStyleAttribute("background", "cyan");` That colors important boxes. Just as a visual aid. On the spread sheet that date has conditional formatting that turns it red of the date is before the current date. (Expired) Is there a way to make the script look for that formatting or preform the same conditional format?

This is what I could come up with,

`if(data[nn][14] < Date(), .setStyleAttribute("background", "red"));`

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting your date objects to "milliseconds from the epoch" using [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime).

```
var dateSerial = data[nn][14].getTime();
var nowSerial = (new Date()).getTime();
var formatColour = (dateSerial < nowSerial)?'red':'cyan';
```

For the other part of your question (specifying how you want the date to appear), take a look at [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_utilities#formatDate).

Comment: So I would put that in and change:

`txt1.setText(data[nn][0]).setStyleAttribute("background", "cyan");`

to:

`txt1.setText(data[nn][0]).setStyleAttribute("background", FormatColor);`

Do I put it between quotes or asterisks? or is it `.formatcolor`
(Changed Colour to Color so I dont confuse myself.)

Comment: It would be good if you provided a larger snippet of your code to see the context, but I would guess yes, something like `txt1.setText(data[nn][0]).setStyleAttribute("background", formatColour);`.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to break lines which I aparently cant do.

Comment: I edited to clear it up my first question but how do I make it show the date as mm/dd/yyyy rather than the long date? I tried var date = (Date(data[nn][14]), "EST", "MM/dd/yyyy") but it literally shows MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: This is working great, Would the same idea work for just a year? like "2012". I tried doing the exact same code on the cell with a year but it just shows a error and doesn't format. I did `var formatColor2 = (data[nn][12] < 2013)?'red':'cyan';` and that works. but If I use nowSerial instead of 2013 everything turns red. I assume because it is turning 2013 into 01/01/2013 which is before today date. How can I make the nowSerial or nowSerial2 as it will have to be output the year as just a 4 digit number?